# Not real random function in a Blogger widget, it always shows 'neighbor' posts from the past

Tags: random, blogger

My blog is 12 years old, I have more than 5000 posts. I am using a widget that shows random posts from a specific label. I set it to show 2 posts in the sidebar, and I noticed that these posts are always 'neighbors', which means they are always from the same month in the past. For example, it's always 2 posts from May 2014, or June 2018. It's never something like: 1 post from May 2014 and the other from June 2018. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Here is the part of the code which (I believe) contains the mistake:

```js
rand=Math.floor((Math.random()*_vRiO.total_entry)+1);
if(rand+bcd140526_post_count>_vRiO.total_entry){
    rand=_vRiO.total_entry-bcd140526_post_count+1;
}
if(rand<1){
    rand=1;
}
var _vXsM=HOST+_s7IgU[159];
if(bcd140526_index_label){
    _vXsM+=_s7IgU[160]+encodeURIComponent(bcd140526_index_label);
}
_vXsM+=_s7IgU[161]+bcd140526_post_count+_s7IgU[162]+rand+_s7IgU[163];
_fIoT(_vXsM);
}else{
    _fYbP(json);
}
}
var _vXsM=HOST+_s7IgU[164];
if(bcd140526_index_label){
    _vXsM+=_s7IgU[165]+encodeURIComponent(bcd140526_index_label);
}
_vXsM+=_s7IgU[166];
if(bcd140526_sort_by==_s7IgU[167]){
_vXsM+=_s7IgU[168];
}else{
    _vXsM+=_s7IgU[169]+bcd140526_post_count;
}
_vXsM+=_s7IgU[170];_fIoT(_vXsM);
```

I can't paste the whole code, the website doesn't let me. But you can get it here: https://sneeit.com/blogger-random-recent-specific-label-posts-widget-all-in-one-post-feed-widget/

My settings:

- Post Count - 2
- Post Order - Random
- Specific Label - Summer
- Show Thumbnail - Checked
- Thumbnail Size - 200
- Show Label - No
- Show Comment Numbers - No
- Show Date - No
- Show Author Name - No
- Show Readmore - No
- Show Snippet - No
- Show Copyright - No
- Design Style - List

Comment: Can you provide the widget code as well? Otherwise the variables are difficult to read?

Comment: Are the blog posts actually from different months? While this randomization error is certainly possible, I think that accidentally reusing code written for the first blogpost (and accidentally using its data) is a lot more likely

Comment: The whole widget code cannot be pasted here, because it says its spam. But you can get it on the link I posted.

Comment: I can't post the whole code because it's too much characters. But I can do it in this way: https://testforthecode.000webhostapp.com/code.txt
@HoldenRohrer can you help me?

Comment: @Bob90sk Are the blogposts actually from the same month every time? Because, if they aren't but just display like they are, this bug is probably quite a bit easier to solve.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer yes, the "random" posts are actually from the same month every time.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer to be more precise: it happened once that one of the posts was from the next month, but still, that was a neighbor post to the other.

Comment: @Bob90sk After deobfuscating the source, I see that this is intended behavior. It chooses a random first post and shows the next post_number posts after it. You may be able to modify it, but this extension's code is really spaghetti-like (it loads jquery and a stylesheet through javascript)

Comment: @HoldenRohrer Well, I'm sure that I'm not able to do that... I thought it would be just chaning a line to something else, LOL.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer Meanwhile I got a response from the code developer. I can't even decide if is he is right: "That's for better performance. We will need to request only one time to get 10 sequenced random posts, but it will be 10 requests if we we need unsequenced posts which will slow down our site a lot."

Comment: @Bob90sk The developer is right about it slowing down the site somewhat, but I think that making even ten API requests will likely cost less than loading the entirety of jquery.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer Well, thanks a lot. I'm gonna try to do my best.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer I couldn't solve it...

Comment: @Bob90sk The modifications will take some work, but the deobfuscated version should be much easier to use. I'd recommend removing `jqueryLoader`, and to get you started: the API requests are `sourceJSfile('/feeds/post/default/-/summer?alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&callback=choosePost')`. You'd probably be better off rewriting the thing from scratch than trying to bodge it on top of this code, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have painstakingly deobfuscated this extension to be able to check how you could modify it (which should be much easier for you if you still want to), and I see that getting "non-neighbor" random numbers is not what this system is designed to do. `choosePost(json)` chooses one post by number to be the starting post, and `makeWidget` (which, bizarrely, uses string concatenation and `document.write` to generate the widget) just uses the first `post_count` posts after the chosen post, so your objective is not (easily) doable.

```js
var show_thumbnail = true;
var show_label = false;
var show_comment_numbers = false;
var show_date = false;
var show_author_name = false;
var show_readmore = false;
var show_snippet = false;
var hide_copyright = true;
var snippet_length = 150;
var post_count = 3;
var thumbnail_size = 140; // v1.5, only effect with list style
var sort_by = 'random'; // latest or random
var index_label = 'summer';
var design_style = 'list'; // list or column
var date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
var lang_readmore = 'Readmore';
var HOST = '';

function sourceJSfile(url) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + url + '"<\/script>');
}

function generateDate(pub_date, format) {
    pub_date = pub_date.split('-');
    date = new Date(pub_date[0], pub_date[1] - 1, pub_date[2].substring(0, 2));
    dd = date.getDate();
    mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    format = format.replace('dd', dd);
    format = format.replace('mm', mm);
    format = format.replace('yyyy', yyyy);
    return format;
}

function cleanContent(content) {
    var tgt = '';
    var imgtag = '<img ';
    var srctag = 'src="';
    var quote = '\"';
    index0 = content.indexOf(imgtag);
    if (index0 != -1) {
        index1 = content.indexOf(srctag, index0);
        index2 = content.indexOf(quote, index1 + srctag.length);
        tgt = content.substring(index1 + srctag.length, index2);
    }
    if (tgt == '') {
        imgtag = 'data-thumbnail-src="';
        srctag = '"';
        index0 = content.indexOf(imgtag);
        if (index0 != -1) {
            index1 = content.indexOf(srctag, index0 + imgtag.length);
            if (index0 != -1) {
                tgt = content.substring(index0 + imgtag.length, index1);
            }
        }
    }
    if (tgt == '') {
        imgtag = '<iframe ';
        srctag = 'src="';
        quote = '"';
        index0 = content.indexOf(imgtag);
        if (index0 != -1) {
            index1 = content.indexOf(srctag, index0);
            if (index0 != -1) {
                index2 = content.indexOf(quote, index1 + srctag.length);
                if (index0 != -1) {
                    tgt = content.substring(index1 + srctag.length, index2);
                    tgt = tgt.replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", '');
                    tgt = tgt.replace("http://www.youtube.com/embed/", '');
                    tgt = tgt.replace('?rel=0', '');
                    tgt = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + tgt + '/mqdefault.jpg';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tgt;
}

function jsonProcessor(json) {
    var data = new Object();
    var regex = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
    data.id = json.feed.id.$t;
    key = 'blog-';
    index = data.id.indexOf(key);
    data.id = data.id.substring(index + key.length);
    data.id = data.id.replace('.comments', '');
    data.cate = new Array();
    if ('category' in json.feed) {
        for (let i = 0; i < json.feed.category.length; i++) {
            data.cate[i] = json.feed.category[i].term;
        }
    }
    data.title = '';
    if ('title' in json.feed) {
        data.title = json.feed.title.$t;
    }
    data.subtitle = '';
    if ('subtitle' in json.feed) {
        data.subtitle = json.feed.subtitle.$t;
    }
    data.admin = new Object();
    data.admin.name = 'Anonymous';
    data.admin.uri = '';
    data.admin.avatar = 'http://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png';
    if ('name' in json.feed.author[0]) {
        data.admin.name = json.feed.author[0].name.$t;
    }
    if ('uri' in json.feed.author[0]) {
        data.admin.uri = json.feed.author[0].uri.$t;
    }
    if ('gd$image' in json.feed.author[0]) {
        if (json.feed.author[0].gd$image.src != 'http://img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif') {
            data.admin.avatar = json.feed.author[0].gd$image.src;
        }
    }
    data.total_entry = Number(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t);
    data.start_index = Number(json.feed.openSearch$startIndex.$t);
    data.item_per_page = Number(json.feed.openSearch$itemsPerPage.$t);
    data.entry_number = 0;
    if ('entry' in json.feed) {
        data.entry_number = json.feed.entry.length;
    }
    data.entry = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < data.entry_number; i++) {
        data.entry[i] = new Object();
        temp = new Object();
        entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        temp.id = entry.id.$t;
        key = 'post-';
        index = temp.id.indexOf(key);
        temp.id = temp.id.substring(index + key.length);
        temp.published = '';
        if ('published' in entry) {
            temp.published = entry.published.$t;
        }
        temp.cate = new Array();
        if ('category' in entry) {
            for (j = 0; j < entry.category.length; j++) {
                temp.cate[j] = entry.category[j].term;
            }
        }
        temp.title = '';
        if ('title' in entry) {
            temp.title = entry.title.$t;
        }
        temp.content = '';
        if ('content' in entry) {
            temp.content = entry.content.$t;
        }
        temp.summary = '';
        if ('summary' in entry) {
            temp.summary = entry.summary.$t;
        }
        if (temp.summary == '') {
            temp.summary = temp.content.replace(regex, '');
        }
        if (temp.content == '') {
            temp.content = temp.summary;
        }
        temp.link = '';
        temp.reply_label = 'comments';
        if ('link' in entry) {
            for (j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++) {
                if (entry.link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
                    temp.link = entry.link[j].href;
                }
                if (entry.link[j].rel == 'replies') {
                    temp.reply_label = entry.link[j].title;
                }
            }
        }
        temp.author = new Object();
        temp.author.name = 'Anonymous';
        temp.author.uri = '';
        temp.author.avatar = 'http://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png';
        a0 = entry.author[0];
        if ('name' in a0) {
            temp.author.name = a0.name.$t;
        }
        if ('uri' in a0) {
            temp.author.uri = a0.uri.$t;
        }
        if ('gd$image' in a0) {
            if (a0.gd$image.src != 'http://img1.blogblog.com/blank.gif') {
                temp.author.avatar = a0.gd$image.src;
            }
        }
        temp.thumbnail = '';
        if ('media$thumbnail' in entry) {
            temp.thumbnail = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
        }
        temp.reply_number = 0;
        if ('thr$total' in entry) {
            temp.reply_number = Number(entry.thr$total.$t);
        }
        temp.reply_label = temp.reply_label.replace(temp.reply_number + ' ', '');
        temp.reply_to = '';
        temp.reply_json = '';
        temp.reply_title = '';
        if ('thr$in-reply-to' in entry) {
            temp.reply_to = entry['thr$in-reply-to'].href;
            temp.reply_json = entry['thr$in-reply-to'].source;
            temp.reply_json = temp.reply_json.replace('/default/', '/summary/');
            temp.reply_json = temp.reply_json + '?alt=json-in-script';
        }
        temp.pid = '';
        if ('gd$extendedProperty' in entry) {
            for (j = 0; j < entry.gd$extendedProperty.length; j++) {
                if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[j].name == 'blogger.itemClass') {
                    temp.pid = entry.gd$extendedProperty[j].value;
                }
            }
        }
        temp.pid = temp.pid.replace('pid-', '');
        data.entry[i] = temp;
    }
    return data;
}
if (typeof(jquery_included) == 'undefined') {
    jquery_included = false;
}

function jqueryLoader() {
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        if (!jquery_included) {
            jquery_included = true;
            var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
            scriptEl.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js');
            scriptEl.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptEl);
        }
        setTimeout(jqueryLoader, 50);
    } else {
        if (!($('link[href*="font-awesome.css"]').length)) {
            linkEl = document.createElement('link');
            linkEl.setAttribute('href', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
            linkEl.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
            document.head.appendChild(linkEl);
        }
    }
}
jqueryLoader();

function makeWidget(json) {
    var div = '<div style="clear:both!important;float:none;!important;line-height:0!important"></div>';
    var jsonOut = jsonProcessor(json);
    var docAppend = '';
    if (jsonOut.total_entry) {
        docAppend += ('<div class="post_feed ' + design_style + ' ' + ((show_thumbnail) ? 'thumb' : 'no-thumb') + '"><ul>');
        for (let i = 0; i < jsonOut.total_entry && i < post_count; i++) {
            p = jsonOut.entry[i];
            docAppend += ('<li class="item item-' + i + '">');
            if (!p.thumbnail) {
                p.thumbnail = cleanContent(p.content);
            }
            if (show_thumbnail && p.thumbnail) {
                var tgt = p.thumbnail;
                if (tgt.indexOf('/s72-c/') != -1){
                    if (design_style === 'column')
                        tgt = tgt.replace('/s72-c/', '/s1600/');
                    else
                        tgt = tgt.replace('/s72-c/', '/s' + thumbnail_size + '-c/');
                } else if (tgt.indexOf('youtube.com') != -1 && tgt.indexOf('/default.') != -1) {
                    tgt = tgt.replace('/default.', '/mqdefault.');
                }
                p.thumbnail = tgt;
                docAppend += ('<a class="thumbnail" style="width:' + thumbnail_size + 'px;height:' + thumbnail_size + 'px;" href="' + p.link + '"><img src="' + p.thumbnail + '"/></a>');
            }
            docAppend += '<div class="item-body">';
            if (show_label && (typeof(p.cate[0]) != 'undefined')) {
                docAppend += ('<a class="cate" href="' + HOST + '/search/label/' + p.cate[0] + '">' + p.cate[0] + '</a>');
            }
            docAppend += ('<h3 class="title"><a href="' + p.link + '">' + p.title + '</a></h3>');
            if (show_author_name || show_comment_numbers || show_date) {
                docAppend += '<div class="meta">';
                if (show_author_name) {
                    docAppend += ('<span class="meta-item author-name"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ' + p.author.name + '</span>');
                }
                if (show_comment_numbers) {
                    docAppend += ('<span class="meta-item comment-number"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> ' + p.reply_number + '</span>');
                }
                if (show_comment_numbers) {
                    docAppend += ('<span class="meta-item date-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ' + generateDate(p.published, date_format) +'</span>');
                }
                docAppend += (div + '</div>' + div);
            }
            if (show_snippet) {
                if (p.summary.length > snippet_length) {
                    p.summary = p.summary.substring(0, snippet_length) + '...';
                }
                if (show_readmore) {
                    p.summary += ' <a href="' + p.link + '#more">' + lang_readmore + '</a>';
                }
                docAppend += ('<p class="snippet">' + p.summary + '</p>');
            }
            docAppend += (div + '</div>' + div);
            docAppend += ('</li>');
        }
        docAppend += ('</ul>');
        if (!hide_copyright) {
            docAppend += div;
            docAppend += '<a target="_blank" class="copyright" href="http://www.sneeit.com/2014/05/blogger-random-recent-specific-label-posts-widget-all-in-one-post-feed-widget" style="font-size: 11px!important;text-align:right;visibility: visible;!important;text-indent:0!important;height:auto!important;width:100%!important;position:static!important;color:#999!important;display:block!important;opacity:1!important;">BloggerWidget</a>';
        }
        docAppend += ('</div>' + div);
    } else {
        docAppend += '<p><em>Have no posts</em><p>';
    }
    document.write(docAppend);
}

function choosePost(json) {
    if (sort_by == 'random') {
        var processedJSON = jsonProcessor(json);
        rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * processedJSON.total_entry) + 1);
        if (rand + post_count > processedJSON.total_entry) {
            rand = processedJSON.total_entry - post_count + 1;
        }
        if (rand < 1) {
            rand = 1;
        }
        var request = HOST + '/feeds/posts/default';
        if (index_label) {
            request += '/-/' + encodeURIComponent(index_label);
        }
        request += '?alt=json-in-script&max-result=' + post_count + '&start-index=' + rand + '&callback=makeWidget';
        sourceJSfile(request);
    } else {
        makeWidget(json);
    }
}
var request = HOST + '/feeds/posts/default';
if (index_label) {
    request += '/-/' + encodeURIComponent(index_label);
}
request += '?alt=json-in-script';
if (sort_by == 'random') {
    request += '&max-results=0';
} else {
    request += '&max-results=' + post_count;
}
request += '&callback=choosePost';
sourceJSfile(request);
```

The modifications will take some work, but the deobfuscated version should be much easier to use. I'd recommend removing `jqueryLoader`, and to get you started: the API requests are `sourceJSfile('/feeds/post/default/-/summer?alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&callback=choosePost')`. You'd probably be better off rewriting the thing from scratch than trying to bodge it on top of this code, I think.

PS: This code loads the entire jquery library so it can load some random stylesheet in `jqueryLoad`.